# Composer naming convention

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, composer-php

I'm wanting to create a WordPress plugin using composer and it also has functionality I can use outside of WordPress and on other projects.

I was thinking I would make the core of it its own package then create a WordPress plugin wrapper.

The naming  conventions for composer are vendor/package so mmano/packagename but can I sub categorise them such as

`mmano/wordpress/plugin/plugin-name` 
Which would also require the core package or is bad practice and something like `mmano/plugin-name` be best

Comment: Looks good, you can namespace them how you like e.g `Mmano\Wordpress\Plugin\PluginName` but as a package name its `vendor/packagename`, `mmano/plugin-name` is fine.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone !

Comment: No worries, setting up can be a bit of tedious (structure, files, unit tests, readme, code coverage, building), I made a script to automate it, you might find it interesting: https://github.com/lcherone/composer-package-generator

Answer (score 0):

The name should consist of vendor name and package name separated by `/`, so `mmano/wordpress/plugin/plugin-name` not really a good idea. `mmano/wordpress-plugin-plugin-name` or `mmano/plugin-name` should be ok.

See the conventions laid out in the official documentation for packagist:

> The name of the package. It consists of vendor name and project name, separated by /. Examples:

> - monolog/monolog
> - igorw/event-source
>   The name must be lowercase and consist of words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match `^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$`.

> The name property is required for published packages (libraries).
> Note: Before Composer version 2.0, a name could contain any character, including white spaces.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#name